# How to use an iCal calendar in a Java program from a calendar URL?

Tags: java, url, icalendar, ical4j

Currently I am using 2 tools to start processing an iCal calendar from URL.  First, using Google Chrome I create a .ics file from the calendar URL (for example I can get URL from AirBnb) and then I use ical4j to process the created file.  Is there any way to use this URL directly in the Java program?

Comment: You mean you have the URL, manually download the ics file using google chrome and then process the calendar file using ical4j. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://airbnb.com/ical/").openStream();
try {
   Calendar cal = new CalendarBuilder().build(is);
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Comment: Or even from Java 7 `try (InputStream is = new URL("http://airbnb.com/ical/").openStream()) { Calendar cal = new CalendarBuilder().build(is); }`